# Let $R$ be a ring such that for all $a,b$ in $R$, $(a^2-a)b=b(a^2-a)$. Then $R$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring such that for all $a,b$ in $R$, $(a^2-a)b=b(a^2-a)$. Then $R$ is commutative.

I am having difficulties making the connection. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are we suddenly getting all these questions about conditions under which rings are commutative? That's at least the third one in the last few hours.

Answer (score 4):

For any $x,y$ in $R$, the relation $(x^2-x)y=y(x^2-x)$ implies that

$$xy-yx=x^2y-yx^2.$$

Now take $a,b$ in $R$ and consider the previous relation for $x=b-a$ and $y=b$ :

$$(b-a)b-b(b-a)=(b-a)^2b-b(b-a)^2~~~~(\ast)$$

Expanding the left side gives $(b-a)b-b(b-a)=ba-ab$.

On the other hand the right side gives

\begin{align}
(b-a)^2b-b(b-a)^2&=(b^2-ab-ba+a^2)b-b(b^2-ab-ba+a^2)\\
&= b^2a-ab^2+a^2b-ba^2\\
&= ba-ab+ab-ba\\
&= 0
\end{align}

Thus $(\ast)$ gives $ba-ab=0$ and $R$ is commutative.

Comment: Very nice. +1${}{}{}{}{}$